# Debug command line arguments in Visual Studio C#, parse issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I must be doing something incredible stupid, as I though the following example of a command line worked in visual studio Debug launch profiles...

```
command -p="some text" -o="some text" -n="some text" -d="some text" -v=false
```

but when I retrieve it using Environment.CommandLine, what I get back is the following

```
<exepath> command "-p=some text" "-o=some text" "-n=some text" "-d=some text" -v=false
```

The quotes are in entirely the wrong locations. I could have sworn this worked, but I must be wrong, any idea what I'm doing wrong? I need them to arrive as entered.

Comment: `<exepath> command -p="some text" -o="some text" -n="some text" -d="some text" -v=false`?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're asking me.  That is what I want to see in Environment.CommandLine, yes.

Comment: Do you have try this syntax?

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly what I have written above, but you have added <exepath> to the beginning.  I do not need to add that within Debug profile as it's already provided.

Comment: Forget, I misleading.

Comment: Your post is unclear. The behavior is by design: `foreach (string arg in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()) { Console.WriteLine($"arg: {arg}");  }`

Comment: The point of quotes in a command line is to join strings together that contain spaces. Under the covers, the OS sees `-p="some text"` as 2 args, `-p="some` and `text"`. The bottom level command processor looks at it and says, "oh there's some quotes in `-p="some`, let's join it up with whatever follows until there's another `"`". The result is an argument that looks like `-p=some text`. Since that contains a space, it presents it to you as `"-p=some text"`.

Comment: As I mentioned above I was using Environment.CommandLine, this returns a single flat string.

Comment: I've already posted a follow up answer as to how I am now handling this, but I think you miss the point, my code was handling command line parsing on its own from a flat string that was provided as is, without any prior manipulation.

Comment: @nick If you are replying to me, what you are seeing is a massaged command line, where the massaging is pretty close to what I described

Answer (score 0):

To get around this, I have changed my code so that my main entry point takes in a string[].  This looks correct, with exception of quotes having been automatically removed, so that it comes out as follows,

```
[0] = command
[1] = -p=some text
[2] = -o=some text
[3] = -n=some text
[4] = -f=some text
[5] = -v=false
```

The bulk of my code is actually command line parsing, hence why I was doing it manually, but this way works so will proceed with this.

Comment: You'll notice that that matches what I described in my comment

Comment: Yup, I had previously avoided this route as I wanted to parse the values manually.  So wrote a whole bunch of unit / integration tests that cover my parser, but unfortunately I didn't have a test case that uncovered this massaged string, my bad!  All working great now, thanks for your input.